# Functor $[\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]\to[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$ has a left adjoint

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with pullbacks and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the category $0\to 1$. Then $[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$ is the category whose objects are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ and whose morphisms are commutative squares in $\mathcal{C}$.Similarly, $[\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$ is the category whose objects are commutative squares in $\mathcal{C}$ and whose morphisms are commutative cubes. We define a functor $P\colon[\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]\to[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$ which takes an object
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>>> C\\
@VVV @VVV \\
B @>>>A
\end{CD}
$$
to the unique map $D\to B\times_A C$ from $D$ to the pullback of $B\rightarrow A\leftarrow C$. I want to show that this functor has a left adjoint.

**My attempt**

First note that $P$ take a morphism

[image]

to the morphism
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D_0 @>>> D_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
B_0\times_{A_0} C_0 @>>> B_1\times_{A_1} C_1
\end{CD}
$$
where the bottom horizontal arrow is obtained from the universal property of $B_1\times_{A_1} C_1$. Drawing some big diagrams show that $P$ is indeed a functor.

I tried to show that for a an object $f\colon X\to Y$ in $[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$, the category $f\downarrow P$ has an initial object. My first guess was that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> Y\\
@V1VV @V1VV \\
X @>f>>Y
\end{CD}
$$
is the initial object, but I am pretty sure that in general, $f\colon X\to Y$ is not in the image of $P$. So now I am trying to show that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> Y\\
@VfVV @V1VV \\
Y @>1>>Y
\end{CD}
$$
is the initial object. It is in $f\downarrow P$ since $Y\cong Y\times_Y Y$. However, for any other object
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> Y\\
@V1VV @V1VV \\
D @>f>> B\times_A C
\end{CD}
$$
in $f\downarrow P$, I can't figure out how to define a map $Y\to D$ so that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\xrightarrow{f} Y @>(1,1)>> X\xrightarrow{f} Y\\
@V(f,1)VV @V(h,g)VV \\
Y\xrightarrow{1}Y @>(\_,g)>> D\to B\times_A C
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. It doesn't seem like such a morphism should exist, so I think I made a mistake somewhere or that $P$ is not a right adjoint. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think what you want is: given a square $(X\to Y) \to (D \to B \times_A C)$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}(f, P(S))$), how to get a cube from the square $(X\to Y) \to (Y \to Y)$ to $(D \to C) \to (B \to A)$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}(L(f), S)$).  And if that's the right diagram, it would be clear: extract the map $X \to D$, form $Y \to C$ as the composition of $Y \to B \times_A C$ with the projection to $C$, and similarly for $Y \to B$ and $Y \to A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand why you need a map $Y \rightarrow D$ ?

Indeed,
$$\require{AMScd}
\left(U = \quad\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{f}VV @VVV \\
Y @>>> Y
\end{CD}, \text{ }\alpha\right)$$
where $$\alpha = \quad\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{1_X}VV @V{1_Y}VV \\
X @>{f}>> Y
\end{CD}$$

is an initial object in the comma category $(f \downarrow P)$.

To see this, consider an arbitrary object
$$\left(L = \quad\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>>> C\\
@VVV @VVV \\
B @>>> A
\end{CD},\text{ }\beta\right)$$
where
$$\require{AMScd}
\beta =\quad\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{\beta_0}VV @V{\beta_1}VV \\
D @>>> B \times_A C
\end{CD}$$
Consider the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{\beta_0}VV @V{\beta_1}VV \\
D @>>> B \times_A C @>>> C\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
 B @= B @>>> A
\end{CD}$$
Use the bottom pullback square to get obvious arrows $Y \rightarrow B, Y \rightarrow C, Y \rightarrow A$.

Check that this defines an arrow $\gamma$ in $[\mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]$ from $U$ to $L$.

This gives rise to a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{1_X}VV @V{1_Y}VV \\
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
D @>>> B \times_A C
\end{CD}$$
where the bottom square is $P(\gamma)$. Note that the uniqueness property of the arrow $\beta_1 : Y \rightarrow B \times_A C$ into the pullback $B \times_A C$ implies that the bottom right vertical arrow in $P(\gamma)$ is $\beta_1$. Further, the composition of the vertical arrows on the left is $\beta_0$ and that of the vertical arrows on the right is $\beta_1$. This says that $P(\gamma) \circ \alpha = \beta$.

Hence, $\gamma : (U, \alpha) \rightarrow (L, \beta)$ is an arrow in the comma category $(f \downarrow P)$.

Moreover, this is the only such arrow as any arrow $\theta : (U, \alpha) \rightarrow (L, \beta)$ in $(f \downarrow P)$ gives rise to a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{1_X}VV @V{1_Y}VV \\
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{\theta_0}VV @V{\theta_1}VV\\
D @>>> B \times_A C
\end{CD}$$ such that the vertical arrows on the left compose to give $\beta_0$ and the vertical arrows on the right compose to give $\beta_1$. Hence, $\theta_0 = \beta_0$ and $\theta_1 = \beta_1$ so that $\beta = \theta$.

Thus, $(U, \alpha)$ is an initial object in the comma category. Hence, $(f \downarrow P)$ has an initial object for every object $f \in [\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]$, so that $P$ has a left adjoint.

Comment: I think I just confused myself with all the arrows and the cubes :) Your answer helped clear things up though, thank you!